# Pandas groupby aggregation with percentages

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
n = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({"val": np.random.randint(1, 10, n), 
                   "cat": np.random.choice(["X", "Y", "Z"], n)})

   val cat
0    3   Z
1    3   X
2    7   Y
3    2   Z
4    4   Y
5    7   X
6    2   X
7    1   X
8    2   X
9    1   Y
```

I want to know the percentage each category `X`, `Y`, and `Z` has of the entire `val` column sum. I can aggregate `df` like this:

```
total_sum = df.val.sum()
#32
s = df.groupby("cat").val.sum().div(total_sum)*100

#this is the desired result in % of total val
cat
X    46.875  #15/32
Y    37.500  #12/32
Z    15.625  #5/32
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

However, I find it rather surprising that pandas seemingly does not have a percentage/frequency function something like `df.groupby("cat").val.freq()` instead of `df.groupby("cat").val.sum()` or `df.groupby("cat").val.mean()`. I assumed this is a common operation, and [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) has implemented this with `normalize=True` - but for groupby aggregation, I cannot find anything similar. Am I missing here something or is there indeed no out-of-the-box function?

Comment: Clearer now? I know how to get the expected result but find it strange that there is no standard pandas implementation for this. If there is none, then there is none. But still puzzling given that this is probably a common operation.

Comment: Got it. Outside of `pandas`, like `r` and statistical package (`sas`/`stata`), even `sql` I cannot think of a *single* aggregate function to calculate sum percentages. It would usually be a multi-step calculation. But hey, you are welcome to start a [Git issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) and work on a new feature PR since `pandas` is an open source project! I would not call it `freq` since this is usually synonymous to `count`. You may have to make a good case to maintainers for this need.

Comment: Okay, just wanted to make sure that I was not simply too blind to find this function ([see this embarrassing example of my pandas skills](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65427794/combine-two-pandas-columns-as-index-create-new-column-with-their-column-names-a)). That you consider me capable of writing efficient code is flattering but misguided.

Comment: I surely do not know all of `pandas`. Consider reviewing all [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html) and [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html) attributes. But layered calculations like sum percentages may not be supported since it opens the door to many other convenience handlers.

Comment: not a real answer, but [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) provides normalizing. The only drawback is that in order to use it here you'll have to introduce a dummy column for the `columns`: `pd.crosstab(df.cat, 1, df.val, aggfunc=sum, normalize='all') * 100`

Comment: Nice. Someone had a go at crosstab but it was not aggregated. Maybe now that it is clear there is no dedicated function I should change the question to "what is the easiest/fastest way to compute it"?